# Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in drupal

Tags: caching, drupal

whenever i flush drupal cache i'm getting "Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in D:\wamp\www\cms_development\includes\database\database.inc on line 2168"

This error also occurs when installing module.

Comment: This is likely caused by a contributed or custom module.  Did you notice when this error appeared, eg. after a module install?  What modules do you have installed?

Comment: After Install multilingual modules

Comment: Thanks. i have disabled my custom module. now its working fine...

Comment: Hi. How to disable to module without accessing the CMS?